# Variables set in a file required within a function still cause a "Notice: Undefined variable" warning

Tags: php

I want to be able to include or require files from the same parent directory (modules) by just typing the name of the file i want to include  without always writing out `require_once('../app/modules/user/user.php')` so i came up with the idea to wrap it all up within function like this:

The index.php file.

```
//index.php

        function require_file($modules=array())
                {
                    foreach($modules as $module) {
                        if (is_dir('../app/modules/' . $module) && file_exists('../app/modules/' . $module . '/' . $module . '.php')) {
                            require_once('../app/modules/' . $module . '/' . $module . '.php');
                        } else {
                            die('The module <strong>' . $module . '</strong> does not exist in the modules directory');
                        }
                    }
                }

    // and then require my files like this:

        $modules = array();

        $modules[] = 'user';

        require_file($modules);
```

This is what my directory looks like:

```
1. app
   - modules
     - user
       - user.php
2. public
   - index.php
```

This is my user.php file:

```
//user.php

$user = 'My Name';
```

Here is the problem;

1. The variables set withing the user.php file if used inside of the index.php still throws ***Notice: Undefined variable: user*** without failing the `is_dir or the file_exists` test, and when it fails it outputs a die massage saying "The module **user** does not exist in the modules directory" like it is supposed to.
2. And when i require the file right after the function to check if the file has be required once before as shown below:

index.php

```
    function require_file($modules=array())
            {
                foreach($modules as $module) {
                    if (is_dir('../app/modules/' . $module) && file_exists('../app/modules/' . $module . '/' . $module . '.php')) {
                        require_once('../app/modules/' . $module . '/' . $module . '.php');
                    } else {
                        die('The module <strong>' . $module . '</strong> does not exist in the modules directory');
                    }
                }
            }

// and then require my files like this:

    $modules = array();

    $modules[] = 'user';

    require_file($modules);

    require_once('../app/modules/user/user.php');
```

It doesn't work because apparently it has already been required once before.

The question is...What am i doing wrong?

Comment: So, you showed us everything except `user.php`. You expect us to guess what is there?

Comment: Its is right there...with a set variable $user.

Comment: You might want to read up about [PHP Autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) which pretty much does exactly what you require (in the context of classes)

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$user` is defined in `require_file` function scope. It is the cause of Notice.

You need to declare `$user` as **global** variable in `user.php` file:

```php
//user.php
global $user;
$user = 'My Name';
```

It's not good idea though. You should create your modules as classes. If you forget about variable `$user` in this module and declare another `$user` variable in another module it will interfere.

Comment: the project is  not object oriented...and am still learning php. can you show me how?

Comment: The answer was edited. Autoloader is not useful if you don't need to load class.

Comment: @GermanLashevich the files can be easily edited to become classes, this would be best in the long run. OP is learning PHP it's the best time to learn about OOP rather than *after* learning procedural... It avoids bad habits such as `global`

Comment: @Martin you are right. But there are two sides: solving current task and learning best practices. The context of current question is not clear enough to show how exactly rewrite code to use classes.

Comment: After some exploring as to what the options are for doing this, there's not much, everything I find that worthy is some sort of mutilation of best practise. Closures could be a way to go but adds various new variables into the functions, and file_get_contents requires using eval, etc.

Comment: There could be a way to use `return` and then each of the includes would need to serialise each included variable for use in the global scope, but yeah... I can't seen much else :-/